# Greeting when meeting somebody a second time in the day?

Tags: usage, politeness, greetings

Let's say I went to the doctor in the morning, greeting the venerable professional with a sincere "こんにちは", and that I left him after he healed my terrible headache.

Now let's say that during the same morning my friend had an accident involving hammers and nails, and requiring me to bring them to that same doctor.

Would it be acceptable to greet my trusted health provider with a "こんにちは" again, or would it sound weird? What, if not "こんにちは", could I say instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [こんにちは and こんばんは only once a day per person?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/%e3%81%93%e3%82%93%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a1%e3%81%af-and-%e3%81%93%e3%82%93%e3%81%b0%e3%82%93%e3%81%af-only-once-a-day-per-person)

Comment: @naruto It's certainly a duplicate and I know the OP doesn't ask, but I'm sure we'd be interested to know what kind of phrases would be acceptable to use in this situation. Thanks.

Comment: The almighty どうも always works, including this case. Or you can say something like 何度もすみません (≒"sorry to take your time again"), or you can *jokingly* say こんにちは pretending it's the first time you met the doctor and probably the doctor will smile back to you.

Comment: I edited in an additional question by user3856370 that is answered by naruto in the comments and by chocolate in the answer section. This question is not answered in the "duplicate" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were in that situation, I wouldn't repeat こんにちは but instead say...

> - どうも。
> - 先ほどはどうも。
> - 先ほどは（どうも）ありがとうございました。
> - 何度もお世話になります。
> - （また）お世話になります。

etc...